# SoapUI - Not able to load global properties from file

Tags: soapui

I have global properties stored in file soapui.properties located in bin folder.
I am referring to properties in my test case, but the property values are not retrieved when the test case is executed. I have followed steps given in the documentation.
Did anyone come across this issue?

Comment: If you have attempted to follow the documentation (online I presume?), and it doesn't work, chances are you have done something wrong. We can keep guessing forever. I think you will increase the chances of getting an answer manyfold, by providing exactly what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your tests through the SoapUI UI part (not through testrunner), then you need to ensure that the global properties are stored in

```
File > Preferences > Global Properties
```

And to retrieve the value of a global property, you can use below syntax.

```
${#Global#PropertyName}
```

But if you need to retrieve the value of a global property within a groovy script or a script assertion, you can use below command:

```
def propertyA = context.expand('${#Global#PropertyName}')
```